# How to define polygons overlapping each other?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, dissolve, overlapping-features

I have a shapefile of landuse in different catchments. I want to calculate the percentage of each landuse category in each catchment using Tabulate Intersection. Before using this tool, I had dissolved the polygons in landuse shapefile using dissolve tool, dissolve field as the landuse category, checked create multipart feature, unchecked unsplit lines.

After using Tabulate intersection, I found out that the percentage of total landuse in some catchments are larger than 100% (around 103%). I think this means that polygons are overlapping each others in these catchment. As a result, I'd like to identify where polygons overlap each others to fix these errors.

Comment: i think this will help you. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29977/correcting-gaps-and-overlapping-polygon-parcels-geometry/29979#29979 or this one http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82597/removal-of-polygon-overlaps/83064#83064

Comment: @iRfAn
Thank you. I managed to find all overlapped polygons using intersect. Could you please let me know what is the best way to fix all these overlaps at once? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finding overlapping polygons/slivers in ArcGIS 10 you want the to use the Data Review toolbar. Specifically you want to go: Data Reviewer toolbar > Feature on Feature Checks > Polygon Overlap/Gap is Sliver Check.

Specifically:

> The Polygon Overlap/Gap is Sliver check finds overlaps and gaps that can be considered slivers

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0102000000mt000000

[image]

If it is an issue of aligning overlapping polygons properly then you can use the information here to help deal with that issue:

[Correcting gaps and overlapping polygon (parcels) geometry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29977/correcting-gaps-and-overlapping-polygon-parcels-geometry)

> The best way is to convert this shape file to file-geodatabase and build the topology in ArcGIS for "Must Not Gaps" and "Must Not Overlap".

The following tools may be of interest depending on the specifics of the situation:

Eliminate: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/data_management_tools/eliminate_data_management_.htm

> Merges the selected polygons with neighboring polygons with the largest shared border or the largest area

Intergrate: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance.

Snapping: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000

> Moves points or vertices to coincide exactly with the vertices, edges, or end points of other features.